# Non-dimensionalization of a Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following system that I want to non-dimensionalize:
\begin{align}
     D'=zD(D(x_{1}-D)/(x_{1}-x_{2}W)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
     W’ = zW (D-x_{3})
\end{align}
where
D is deer, W is wolves, with units of animals/$\text{meter}^2$.

The parameters are $z, x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ all positive.

So, I know that first I need to identify the independent and dependent variables and then
replace each of them with a quantity scaled relative to a characteristic unit. But, I'm having trouble with the units and don't really know where to go from here.

I have:
\begin{align*}
d=\frac{D}{D_{c}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
w=\frac{W}{W_{c}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\tau=\frac{t}{t_{c}}
\end{align*}

for the parameters, but that's all I got so far.